# Assets for Magento 2 site not rendering when running on docker

Tags: magento2

I"m working on spinning up my first magento 2 site and I decided to use Docker to allow for a quick and easy development environment.

I got the site to spin up but when it is up I find that none of the assets or styles are being loaded and i'm getting an error of "net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED" Image of the error can be found here:

[image]

I have added the project to a public repo if anyone wants to pull it down and play with it. https://github.com/ajmyers01/magento_docker

I'm unsure why it can't seem to find the assets, any help would be fabulous

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your github readme, you have `http://fwc.docker:8000/` as the base url, but it tries to load the assets from `http://fwc.docker/`, which would be `http://fwc.docker:80/`

I think you just have to set the magento base url to `http://fwc.docker:8000/` under system -> configuration -> web -> base_url (or since the backend won't work also most likely you can change it in the database in the core_config_data table. Search for the Path `web/unsecure/base_url`)

Comment: Your a hero, I just needed to change the port back to 80:80 in my docker compose and rebuild the image. Now it works like a champ ! Your the best David!